# Why are these LED current limiting resistors so big?

Tags: led, battery-charging, current-limiting

I'm looking at the charging circuit for a lithium ion battery that was made by Adafruit.  Here's an excerpt:

[image]

If there's a 5V rail from the USB port and a 470 Ohms resistor, is that limiting the current through the LED to 6 mA just to keep the brightness low?  The datasheet for the charger has 470 Ohms resistors in the reference design too.  I'm just not sure why.

Comment: Modern LEDs are quite efficient, and the application here is just a status indicator, not trying to light up a room. Why would you waste more power than you need?

Comment: If it's just an indicator, you only need it to be visibly on, and for most LEDs 5mA or so is more than enough for that.

Comment: You may find some useful details on LED indicators here, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/378129/117785

Comment: 6 mA x 3V = 18 mW. Assume 150 lm/Watt from LED at low current. At 150 lm/W = 27 lm. Look at that at say 1metre and assume radiation angle of LED is such that it illuminates 1/4 say of available area. Full sphere =  4Pir^2 so 1/4 sphere at 1m = Pi^R^2 = 3.14 m^2. Illuminance = 27 lm /3.14 ~= 10 lm/m^2. That's nicely visible but not bright-distracting-bright. Sounds good. E&)E.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [MCP73831](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20001984g.pdf) datasheet specifies a maximum source/sink current on the STAT pin of 35 mA and 25 mA respectively - so if the designer wanted brighter LEDs she could use lower-value resistors without worrying about overloading the output drivers on the charge controller IC. Higher currents would eat into the current available for charging, but not really to a significant extent.

So yes, I think the reason is simply that 6 mA is plenty bright enough for a status LED. Some would even say it's too bright, especially with modern high-efficiency LEDs.