# USB Communication

Tags: usb, connector, digital-communications, hardware, interface

is it safe to add LEDs with D+ and D- line communication?
I did this schematic(attached) and the communication does not work.
where is the problem? [image]

Comment: I would use TTL buffers in order not to disrupt the communication on the data line.

Comment: @swer, the OP can't use TTL buffers. USB D+ and D- aren't compatible with TTL levels.

Comment: You need to know the USB type you are trying to monitor. USB 1.1 devices have ±3.3-V signal levels and can operate at low- and full speeds. USB 2.0 devices have ±400-mV signal levels and can operate at low-, full-, and high speeds. Teo Comparators would probably be your best choice.

Comment: It should work if you use so-called "ultrabright" LEDs, typically Green and Blue (or any phosphor color), made on 2.7-3.6V InGaN technology, with high brightness at low (0.5-1mA) current. See also https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/378129/117785 Or use CMOS-3v3 logic to buffer the signals.

Answer (score 5):

D+ (or D- for low speed) is pulled up by an 1k5 resistor. Thus the current into the LED messes up "device attached" detection.

Once enumerated, all devices get the SOF token every *milli*second. That would light up both LEDs all the time, if the series resistors are much larger.

Messing with the data lines won't work with USB 2.0 high speed frequencies.