# Schmitt trigger VS transistor

Tags: transistors, current, led-driver, hardware, schmitt-trigger

Can you please explain for me what is the difference between Schmitt trigger and transistor, especially in driving LEDs and in current consumption.

**EDIT:** There's answers and comments which seem to be based on an assumption that I know nothing.

To make things more clear I add that I used a transistor to drive LED with USB differential lines (D+ and D-) in USB but I think this is not good because D+ and D- are sensitive to the load. So my hierarchical superior propose to me to use Schmitt trigger. So I ask the question the difference between transistor and schmitt trigger in driving LED, is there any difference to minimise the load in USB datalines?

Comment: Do you have any particular schematic to show as example?

Comment: A warm welcome to the site. Please note that it's not a free design house, homework-answering service or on-line technical encyclopaedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've already done as much as you possibly could - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. This is one line, expecting mountains of effort in return. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your own work and own findings in considerable detail. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers it will attract. Again, welcome.

Comment: This really is underresearched. I think it's fair to assume you've read at least the start of both wikipedia pages on transistors and Schmitt triggers, and came to the conclusion they are not in the same *category* of things.

Comment: I think you already have a good answer for your previous and related question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/565487/usb-communication

Answer (score 2):

Schmitt trigger is a circuit which is designed to detect if a certain voltage is exceeded. It has 2 output states. It has hysteresis to prevent oscillations caused by noise at the state transition edge.

Transistor is a component which is commonly used in circuits which switch signals, amplify them, generate them or detect their states like the Schmitt trigger does.

Your question shows that you aim low cost and minimal energy waste. Unfortunately as well you could ask "should I use nails or prebuilt house elements to build a house?" The things are not comparable without knowing how you are going to use nails to get something which is comparable with prebuilt elements.